# Knockout js and jquery auto complete cant get value

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

i am trying to get the value of jquery auto complete, this i can do, the problem is i have multiple auto selects on the same page that are in a foreach loop so it will always bring back the same value for all changes.
view

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: new_contact">
  <tr>
      <div data-bind="html: $root.input, attr: { style: 'margin-bottom: 15px' }, event: { change: $root.updateEmailAddress }" /> </div>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

model

```
root.updateEmailAddress = function(data, event)
{     
  var test = $('.ui-autocomplete-input').val()
  console.log(test)
}
```

html: $root.input is just a obseravble that contain the input field

i have tried using

```
$(this).find(.ui-autocomplete-input').val()
```

but nothing i try with jquery seems to work
any ideas

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a custom binding:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.autocomplete={
  init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
          $(element).on('change', function() {
             var test=$(this).val();
             console.log(test);
          });
        }
};
```

Then remove the `change` section from your `attr` binding and add `, autocomplete` to the bindings.